# Why do we remain silent when praying asr and dhuhr?

Tags: salat, fiqh, practical-islam

Assalamu alaikum

I want ask about salah dhuhr and 'asr Why when we salah 'asr and dhuhr always not speak like other like salah maghrib and 'isha' ?

Comment: Seems to be covered in https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24495/13438