# Should Takbir Tahrima be said loudly?

Tags: salat, fiqh, fard, takbir

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Sayyidil-Mursalin wa 'ala 'Alihi wa Sahbihi Ajma'in.

---

**Takbir Tahrima** is a fard (obligatory) rukn of Salah. **But should it be said loudly? Or can it be said just by whispering (with very low voice) or silently (quietly)?**

For both "yes" and no "answer" I need proof.

**In case of "yes", what do dumb or deaf people do?**

---

**Update**

Special case that I am concerned with is that **if Takbeer is said quietly (without making any sound) then Salah is not accepted.** I'd like to know if this claim has base for. The concern comes from the fact that **Takbir Tahrima** is fard (obligatory) rukn of Salah.

Comment: Poeple who are deaf or dumb would pray the way the can. As for your question whether or not the takbir for starting the prayer should be said loudly it should have been covered already in [Do we have to say allahu akbar loudly in every rakat of every salat?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/21404/do-we-have-to-say-allahu-akbar-loudly-in-every-rakat-of-every-salat)

Comment: @Medi1Saif | Your answer has led me to conclusion that we can say the Takbeer loudly or by whispering or silently. Is it correct (your own opinion)?

Comment: My opinion if you are led by an imam him saying it loudly is ok and you shouldn't raise your voice at least not in a manner that it disturbs anybody. If you are alone you may do it either way. If you are the imam you certainly must say it loudly

Comment: Jazakallah khairan

Comment: If you think that your inquiry is answered there, please mark your post as a duplicate.

Comment: Well, I was looking for an evidence. I am worried that saying Takbeer quietly may annul Salah. But your answer, you gave link to, and your comment is calming me down for now. You gave a link to fatwa at islamqa.info in your post. It provides some sources, thus seems to contain evidence. I have to study them.

Comment: @Medi1Saif | Is that a problem if we leave the question open? What if someone decides to post something an extraordinary. Why not wait for other answers?!

Comment: Well IMHO a reference or an evidence was mentioned in my answer it is based on it that scholars made different choices. I don't intend to close a question if OP doesn't think his question was answered, but that remains my personal choice.

Comment: My problem is, as I already said, I am worried that **if Takbeer is said quietly then Salah is not accepted.** And I was looking for an evidence. If you wish you can make changes to your answer to enlighten this issue.

Comment: @Medi1Saif | Your answer does not explain what dumb or deaf people do.

Comment: What dumb or deaf people do is obvious as Allah doesn't ask a person to do something he is not able to do. And there's no reason to worry as the matter is not crucial for the acceptance or validity of the prayer except for the case of an imam leading a congregation.